# When do Koroks start telling you to go to the Lost Woods?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

At some point in Tears of the Kingdom, whenever I found a Korok they would tell me to go see the Lost Woods. A Korok also appeared outside the Lost Woods that hinted how to get through the woods. However, I noticed that some other players [never came across](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/266202-the-legend-of-zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom/80464732) [this hint](https://old.reddit.com/r/tearsofthekingdom/comments/13p4a73/spoilers_they_really_dropped_the_ball_on_the_lost/jl7t1f3/?context=1).

This made me wonder, what condition needs to be met before Koroks start telling you about the Lost Woods?

Comment: Perhaps it could be related to the quest Trail of the Master Sword?

Comment: I believe the trigger must be the meeting with Purah and the Sages after fighting puppet Zelda in Hyrule Castle, though I can't confirm for sure. After I'd had that meeting the very next Korok I found had a unique text line telling me he was happy to hear the problems in Korok forest had been cleared up (even though I'd cleared it up long before, and found many Koroks in the interim).

Comment: @Showsni Just had the same experience… cleared Crisis at Hyrule Castle; and the the next Korok mentioned the lost woods being back to normal.